# what will be the regular expression for allowing alphanumeric characters, space, hypen in between, dot at the end or in between

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am new to regular expression. I am using regular expression in SQL query. And want to display all the records which contain anything other than: Alphanumeric characters, white spaces, hyphen(-) in between the string, dot(.)in the end and in between the string.
I have been able to do for alphanumeric characters and spaces. But hyphen and dot are creating problem.

for eg: "first.name", "firstname." should not come but ".firstname" should come in the result.

And "first-name" should not come but "-firstname" and "firstname-" should come in the result.

As of now i have done this.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE  column1 like '.%' or column1  like '-%' or
 regexp_like(column1 ,'[^[:alnum:]^[:blank:]]');
```

The above query is working in the way that it allows dot and hyphen at any place in the string. And not the places i want as discussed above.

Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: You say *other than alphanumeric* but the example is `.firstname`. This is unclear. Maybe you just need `REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '^[.-]?[[:alnum:][:blank:]]+-?$')`?

Comment: because .firstname has dot in it in the begining. So that is why it should be populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a whole lot of solutions. Finally the below is exactly working the way i wanted.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (INSTR(column1,'.', 1, 1))=1
or (INSTR(column1,'-', 1, 1))=1 or (INSTR(column1,'-', 1,1)=length(column1))
or (REGEXP_LIKE(column1,'[^[:alnum:]^[:blank:]-.]'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've create table just  like yours and this statement

```
select * from tmp where x like '.%' OR x like '-%' or x like '%-';
```

works perfectly fine - only . and -
:)

Comment: I already tried this. This will allow dot and hyphen at any position

Answer (score 1):

I confirm Michal solution:

```
SELECT * FROM
             (select 'first.name' x from dual
   union all select 'firstname.' from dual
   union all select '.firstname' from dual
   union all select 'first-name' from dual
   union all select 'firstname-' from dual
   union all select 'firs#@tname' from dual
   union all select 'firs  tname' from dual
   union all select '#@hh tname' from dual
   union all select '-firstname' from dual
   union all select 'firstname' from dual)
 where x like '.%' OR x like '-%' or x like '%-'
or (regexp_like(x ,'[^[:alnum:]^[:blank:]]') and x not like '%-%' and x not like '%.%') 
;
```

Leading to

```
.firstname 
firstname- 
firs#@tname
#@hh tname
-firstname
```

Comment: i have to use this along with regular expression. and using this with regex of alphanumeric characters and spaces in or condition with the above. wont give the desired result

Comment: Maybe you want to exclude the `-` and `.`cases from the second part of the clause... solution updated. But your requirement is not completely clear. I advise you give a bigger set and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be written as a single regex without recourse to the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column1 ,'(^[.-]|-$)|[^a-zA-Z0-9 \t.-]')
```

Here the regex is looking for any string that matches the following pattern:

- Starts with `.` or `-` or ends with `-`
- Contains a character other than a letter (`a-zA-Z`) or number (`0-9`) or space/tab (this is what the POSIX class `[:blank:]` is, as opposed to `[:space:]` which is all whitespace) or `.` or `-`.

Please see [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/18203). Note that I used the same test data as in the accepted answer.